# Jupyter: Get multi-line input from user

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I tried for several hours to get solution to my basic question with out success.
How can I get in **Jupyter**, multi-line input from user (Python3)?
Pay attention that the question is regard to user input in Jupyter.

I have been try:

1. widgets.Text:

   ```
   from IPython.display import display
   text = widgets.Text()
   display(text)
   button = widgets.Button(description="Send")
   display(button)

   def on_button_clicked(b):
       print(text.value)

   button.on_click(on_button_clicked)`
   ```
2. Special keys:

   ```
   print ("Enter/Paste your content. Ctrl-D to save it.")
   contents = []
   line = "vv"
   while line != "":
       try:
           line = input("")
       except EOFError:
           break
       contents.append(line)
   ```

and more..

Thanks for you time and help,
Oran

Comment: This is not a duplicate. Methods like `sys.stdin.read()` just DO NOT WORK in jupyter. REOPEN.